# keep updating progressbar after segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I have an app with only a `WebViewController` and a WebView inside, and the content of the `WebView` is changed using a `MenuViewController` implementing `SWRevealViewController`.

When a download task is started inside the `ViewController` I want to show a `progressView` to show progress and keep being updated even if user selects another item from the Menu.

The problem is that everytime a Menu item is selected, the `progressView` is returned to 0, and is not updated anymore.

> ```
> WebViewController.m
> ```

```
- (void) startDownload:(NSString*)manyURLS {
    NSLog(@"Downloading...");
    self.progressView.hidden = NO;
    //download the files in a seperate thread.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        NSError *error = nil; //error setting
        NSString *index;
        int numItems;
        float progress;

        for (int i = 1; i <= numItems; i++) {
        // download url item           

            NSLog(@"%f", progress);
            progress = (double)i/(double)numItems;

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                self.progressView.progress = progress;
            });
        }

        //saving is done on main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"Download Finished !");
            self.progressView.hidden = YES;
        });
    });
}
```

> ```
> MenuViewController.m
> ```

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ( [segue isKindOfClass: [SWRevealViewControllerSegue class]] ) {
        SWRevealViewControllerSegue *swSegue = (SWRevealViewControllerSegue*) segue;

        swSegue.performBlock = ^(SWRevealViewControllerSegue* rvc_segue, UIViewController* svc, UIViewController* dvc) {

        UINavigationController* navController = (UINavigationController*)self.revealViewController.frontViewController;
        [navController setViewControllers: @[dvc] animated: NO ];
        self.revealViewController.rearViewRevealWidth=160;
        self.revealViewController.rightViewRevealWidth=160;
        [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];
    };

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSUInteger selectedSection = indexPath.section;
    WebViewController *webController = segue.destinationViewController;

    switch (selectedSection) {
        case 0:
            webController.webPage = [firstSectionURLs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            break;
        case 1:
            webController.webPage = [secondSectionURLs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            break;
        case 2:
            [self createMail];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

How can I navigate between the Menu options and keep updating the progressView after Segue?

Comment: I've never used the SWRevealViewController. Is the controller where you have the progress bar deallocated when you choose another menu item (you can implement dealloc and put a log in there to check)?

Comment: sorry, i'm not pretty sure how to do the deallocation, i'm new in iOS. I tried -(void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    NSLog(@"goodbye world");
}
But as I'm using ARC it creates an error.

Comment: You shouldn't be calling super. That's not allowed under ARC. Delete that line, and it should work correctly.

Comment: I added the dealloc method inside every implementation, everytime a menu item is selected there are two places where dealloc is called inside SWRevealController

Comment: If it's called in WebViewController, then that's your problem; you must be instantiating a new WebViewController. I don't know this for sure, but using the SWRevealViewController might not work for what you're trying to do.